# 301 redirect with query parameters and ~ in URL

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I have a redirect problem where I would like to redirect a url with query parameters to another PDF entirely, e.g.:

Original URL:
https://www.foo.bar.com/~/bar.pdf?la

Redirect URL:
https://www.bar.foo.com/foo.pdf

Currently my rewrite rule is as shown below:

```
RewriteRule ^/~/bar.pdf?la https://www.bar.foo.com/foo.pdf [R=301,L,NC]
```

How can I write a 301 redirect that both accounts for the tilde and the query parameter?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your rule `RewriteRule ^/~/bar.pdf?la https://www.bar.foo.com/foo.pdf [R=301,L,NC]` has several issues .

First , `RewriteRule ^/` it is not applicable here so `RewriteRule ^` is enough.
Second , you should escape `~` like this `RewriteRule ^\~`
and finally , dont't write query string with `RewriteRule` like `bar.pdf?la` because it is not a pert of `URI`.

The line should look like this :

```
RewriteRule ^\~/bar.pdf https://www.bar.foo.com/foo.pdf [R=301,L,NC]
```

But the query string may append to new target , to prevent that add `?` at the end of target this :

```
RewriteRule ^\~/bar.pdf https://www.bar.foo.com/foo.pdf? [R=301,L,NC]
```

If you want to use query string value , you may add condition before that to utilize it:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
```

you could change `^(.*)$` to whatever you want and you could use it in target like this example :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://www.whatever.com/%1/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

So , `%1` refer to this condition `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$` and `$1` refer to this condition `RewriteRule ^(.*)$` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)
 directive to check the url query string. You can not do that in `RewriteRule` . The querystring in your url is `la` .

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond ℅{QUERY_STRING} ^la$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*bar\.pdf$ /foo.pdf? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Am I able to implement a Rewrite Condition in a .rewrite file with dozens of rewrite rules and ensure it is only applicable to one rule?

Comment: @Franchise you can only use one `Rule` per `RewriteCond(s)` https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: Does this take into account the ~?